# Getting the length of a json array with dplyr/tidyverse

Tags: r, json, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a column that contains json (i.e. str) arrays

```
"[\n \"x\", |\"y\"]"
```

How can I get the length of all of these arrays?

I tried:

```
data_analysis  <- data  |>
    mutate(out=list(fromJSON(get(outcome))))
```

and this gives me a column of tibbles and I can do

```
length(data_analysis$out[[87]])
```

to get the length of the list of the 87th element, but how can I apply this in a pipe.

Also many of the jsons are `"[]"`

Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not reproducible. The code is not applicable to the toy data. Your desired output is entirely missing. Perhaps `data |> dplyr::mutate(json_length = nchar(outcome))`? It depens on what is length for you? Including `[` and `]`, and other special characters? Including white spaces?

Comment: The question is closed so I can't post an answer, but you might try CRAN package [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io) and, for the data in @Allen Cameron's answer, `mutate(outcome_length = j_query(outcome, "length(@)"))`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the length of the json array implied by each string, then you can use `lengths` after you `lapply` the function `fromJSON` on the column of interest:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(outcome = c("[\n \"x\", \"y\"]",
                               "[\n \"x\", \"y\", \"z\"]",
                               "[\n \"x\", \"y\"]"))

data %>%
  mutate(out = lengths(lapply(outcome, jsonlite::fromJSON)))
#>              outcome out
#> 1      [\n "x", "y"]   2
#> 2 [\n "x", "y", "z"]   3
#> 3      [\n "x", "y"]   2
```